# EXCEL Online - Pull entire column of data where condition (without VBA)

Tags: excel

trying to figure out how to summarise some data quickly.

I have here an example of what I am trying to do in the attached picture.

Basically - I have a yearly planner with some names, and on various dates there's a X marking that person on that date.

I need to be able to summarise on either the bottom or a new sheet, the total days as a list of days where there's a mark. The data also needs to be presented in the same format - with all names shown even if there's a blank in that days cell.

I can't use VBA because I'm forced to use EXCEL online unfortunately.

I basically want (from a coders perspective) select column where column not null.

Can anyone help me understand how I would do this please? If not I'll have to manually go through and pull out the columns on a weekly basis

Thanks!

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clMZm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took a few hours to build a solution.

https://1drv.ms/x/s!AncAhUkdErOkgqRwUEztHeWbj3LkqA?e=s4x0SI

```
A3  =IF(COUNTIF(C3:L3;"x")>0;ROW();"")
C1  =IF(COUNTIF(C3:C12;"x")>0;COLUMN();"")
    
B17 =IFERROR(INDEX($B$3:$B$12;MATCH(SMALL($A$3:$A$12;ROWS($A$3:A3));$A$3:$A$12;0));"")
C16 =IF(IFERROR(SMALL($C$1:$L$1;COLUMNS($C$1:C1));"")<>"";HLOOKUP(IFERROR(SMALL($C$1:$L$1;COLUMNS($C$1:C1));"");$C$1:$L$2;2);"")
C17 =IF(IFNA(INDEX($C$3:$L$12;MATCH($B17;$B$3:$B$12;0);MATCH(C$16;$C$2:$L$2;0));"")=0;"";IFNA(INDEX($C$3:$L$12;MATCH($B17;$B$3:$B$12;0);MATCH(C$16;$C$2:$L$2;0));""))
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting solution to do horizontal and vertical counts beforehand and use those for the lookup references.

This is a great solution, thank you very much!